# How to mock an external enum setting in Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, enums, jasmine

I'm testing an AngularJS service with Jasmine. The service calls a function in another service using an enum from another module as a parameter.

```
public getSavedColumns = (): ng.IPromise<GridColumn[]> => {
    return this.productSettingsService.readProjectSetting(
        psfc.ApplicationId.Calculator, this.getColumnStorageProperty())
        .then(response => { /**/ });
};
```

`psfc.ApplicationId` is an enum in another module:

```
export enum ApplicationId {
    Calculator = 2636
}
```

The Jasmine tests fail with the error:

> TypeError 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'psfc.ApplicationId.Calculator')

I thought I could mock the enum in the test, but it doesn't change the outcome.

```
beforeEach(() => {
    angular.mock.module('pw_psfc',
        $provide => {
            $provide.constant('psfc.ApplicationId.Calculator', 0);
        });
});
```

Comment: It looks like `psfc` is a global namespace, not an angular module. The angular provider is for angular dependencies. You need to include the module(s) that create the `psfc` namespace at testing time, or you need to create mocks for those modules and load them at testing time.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem by including the file with the exported enum in the karma configuration. Five months is a pretty slow learning curve, but I'm getting there! =~)